# Why use "node.getNext( ) == null" as a convention for defunct node?

Tags: java, data-structures

This is a code fragment from the book "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java (6th Ed.)" This is method is part of the LinkedPositionalList implementation.
I don't understand exactly what does the line:
    "if (node.getNext( ) == null) // convention for defunct node"
is for. I'd appreciate some explanation about its functionality.

```
// private utilities
/** Validates the position and returns it as a node. */

private Node<E> validate(Position<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException { 

if (!(p instanceof Node)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid p");

Node<E> node = (Node<E>) p; // safe cast

if (node.getNext( ) == null) // convention for defunct node
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("p is no longer in the list");

return node;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this code always either returns its argument or throws. Can you tell us what the book your reading *says* this code is supposed to do? For instance, what is a "node" in this context? Is it a node of a graph or something else? That may help us figure out why a node without a next is considered defunct.

Comment: The nodes are used as the builder blocks of the LinkedPositionalList, which is based on a DoublyLinkedList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation in the book you're asking about uses an explicit `trailer` node that represents a "one past the end" position in the structure.  Therefore, all nodes in the list must have a next node.  Therefore, if a node's `getNext()` method returns `null` that node isn't in the list.

Answer (score 1):

In this case ***defunct node*** means a non existent node.

```
if (node.getNext( ) == null) // convention for defunct node
```

In this case, the node `p` has a method called `getNext()` which can return null, if it does, then it means its the last of the nodes. *In other words there is no next node.*

This kind of structures, as the name implies, link between each other. getNext() should return a position in memory where the next node is, if such position is not existent then, there is no node there.

Usually `node` will likely have a method called `setNext(Position<E> next)` this is the counterpart that saves the position of the next item for this node.

Answer (score 0):

If you read in the book the "Doubly Linked list Implementation" part of chapter 7 explains the *defunct position* notion as a result of getting rid of any removed position (node) in the list. Because the `remove()` method implements that the position to be deleted is set to `null` value.

So the `validate()` method actually checks if the input position is not removed from the list.. how? once again, by checking if calling `getNext()` on it would get `null` value. If so, then it must have been set to `null` as a deleted position using the `remove()` method. Therefore it throws an error as the input position p is **no longer** in the list (since it's a deleted position).

To better understand, just refer to the delete() method there in the book. Here it is from the book:

```
// Removes the element stored at Position p and returns it (invalidating p).
public E remove(Position<E> p) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  Node<E> node = validate(p);
  Node<E> predecessor = node.getPrev();
  Node<E> successor = node.getNext();
  predecessor.setNext(successor);
  successor.setPrev(predecessor);
  size−−;
  E answer = node.getElement();
  node.setElement(null);          // help with garbage collection
  node.setNext(null);             // and convention for defunct node
  node.setPrev(null);
  return answer;
}
```